# Как включить поддержку fork (много-процессорность) в PHP?

Tags: unix, php, mac

Здравствуйте!

Не могу разобраться, как выполнить следующий код, организующий разветвление процессов.

```
<?php

$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid == -1) {
    echo 'Fork error.';
}

elseif ($pid) {
    echo 'Parent process.';
}

else {
    echo 'Children process.';
}

?>
```

Операционная система - Mac OS X Lion Server, версия PHP 5.3.6. Запускаю скрипт из терминала и вот что он выдаёт:

[image]

Я так понимаю, у меня скрипт запускается без поддержки pcntl, но я не понимаю, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно собрать php с этим "–-enable-pcntl"

Comment: Запускал в терминале так:
"php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/multi/index.php –-enable-pcntl".
Выдаёт ту же ошибку.
Всё больше склоняюсь к тому что не установлен этот модуль.

Comment: Собрать, а не запустить. В смысле, нужно PHP пересобирать, из исходников.

Comment: Ясна! Никогда этим не занимался... буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Надо собирать PHP с поддержкой pcntl. Для MacPorts (чтобы не совсем уж хардкорно руками с `./configure --enable-pcntl && make && sudo make install`) [пишут вот такое](http://codeshepherd.blogspot.com/2009/10/multithreading-in-php-on-mac-osx.html):

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port update outdated
sudo port install php5-pcntl
```

(Правду пишут или нет — не знаю, OS X нет под руками, да и пользовался я ей полтора раза в жизни. Как быть в случае не с MacPorts, а, скажем, с Homebrew — хз, надо гуглить, извините.)

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Завтра буду устанавливать, так как MacPorts требует установленных XCode и X11 а XCode как раз отсутствует! Кстати сейчас погуглил и нашёл очень интересную статью как раз по установке и конфигурации  PHP (а так же Apache и MySQL) через MacPorts (http://makegood.ru/tools/macports-mamp/).